# When is $f(\mathbf x,0)$ irreducible for an irreducible power series $f(\mathbf x,\mathbf y)$?

Tags: complex-analysis, algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry

Suppose $f(\mathbf{x,y}) \in \mathbb C\{x_1, \dotsc, x_n, y_1, \dotsc, y_m\}$ is an irreducible convergent power series (irreducible in the ring theoretic sense). Do we have good conditions to decide if $$ f(\mathbf x,0) \in \mathbb C\{x_1, \dotsc, x_n\}$$
is irreducible? We probably want to exclude the case that $f(\mathbf x,0)$ is constant, i.e. suppose $f - f(0,0) \notin (y_1, \dotsc, y_m)$.

Equivalently, what are conditions that the irreducible germ of an analytic hypersurface $\{f = 0\} = \mathcal Y \subset (\mathbb C^n \times \mathbb C^m,0)$ remains irreducible when intersecting with $\mathbb C^n \times 0$?

For a counterexample consider $f(x,y,z) = xy - z^2$, which factors for $z = 0$. Geometrically this is a singular cone, intersected with a plane, which results in two intersecting lines.

Comment: Smoothness. ${}{}{}$